# auto generate AD network Diagram with visio or other tools

Tags: active-directory, schema, visio

It's there a way in visio to automaticly design the Network Diagram of my domain ?

I found Microsoft Active Directory Topology Diagrammer, but this software not design the member of my domain.

I need to get all member in my domain on a visio schema. It's ther a tool to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to write your own code to do it.  Check out this series of articles from Scripting Guy on doing a network diagram with Powershell and Visio.  http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/12/hey-scripting-guy-january-12-2010.aspx

Comment: not found http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/12/hey-scripting-guy-january-12-2010.aspx